# Binding not updating when there is frame dropping in QML

Tags: qt, binding, qml

I have a UI element, which appears while I do some calculation and disappears when the calculation finished. The appearing and disappearing is animated. The animation animates the item's `implicitHeight` from `0` to `X` and vice-versa. These items live in a `ListView` as delegates. The `ListView` is wrapped in an `Item` as the root element of this component. The `implicitHeight` of this root element depends on, aka is binded to the `contentHeight` of the `ListView`. The width of this root element is set where the component is used. Here you can see my explanation in code:

```
Item {
    id: _root

    implicitHeight: _listView.contentHeight

    ListView {
        id: _listView

        width: _root.width
        height: contentHeight

        delegates: AnimatingItem {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The `AnimatingItem`s in the code have predefined `height` (not necessarily the same for all). I wrote a small debug code piece which basically writes the `ListView`'s `contentHeight`, `childrenRect.height`, `height` and the root item's `implicitHeight` to the console on a button press.

In most cases when ever I press this button to print out those values, like during a calculation when the item is present (= `X`) or when there is no calculation therefore the item is hidden (= `0`), they all match.

In certain scenarios when I do some really heavy calculation though, when even the UI freezes/drops frames and the calculation finishes and I press the debug button all the `ListView`'s values match (= `0`), but the items's `implicitHeight` differs (= `X`). The weird thing is that the `AnimatingItem`'s or in other words the `ListView` disappears thus there is no visible item, but if I anchor a `Rectangle` to the top of this item then it will float in the air instead of moving down as the `ListView` disappears.

Is it possible that if I have a really heavy calculation one or more bindings can "forget" to update due to dropping frames?

Comment: What platform is it running?

Comment: I am running it on a Mac (10.11.16) and Qt 5.6.2.

Comment: **1.** Don't overdo it with JS. For more complex functions, put them in C++ **2.** Keep in mind the JS Optimizations. Try to avoid using `var/variant`-properties in Bindings. Try to use only single line expressions. No loops, nor if else, no return in Bindings. **3.** in Functions if you need values from somewhere else more often, put them in the scope by storing them in a intermediate variable. `id.property.property.property.property` is comparably slow to look up. **BUT** Try to avoid usage of *3* and *4* in Bindings. Though it is improving the performance of JS, avoiding it is even better.

Comment: See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#javascript-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some platforms animations don't run in a dedicated thread, but I don't think that's the case of Mac OS. So dropping frames due to lack of graphics performance should not cause skips in binding evaluations. Now if you have a CPU hotspot as a cause of the dropped frame, that's a different story. The animation is synced to the event loop rate as well as the scenegraph rate, so if your event loop is stalling, then it is simply not making the value change, which is why you don't get reevaluations.

As a rule of thumb, you shold **never ever** do heavy calculations in the main/gui thread. If it causes the GUI to freeze for more than 10 msec you need to offload it to a dedicated thread, and update the results asynchronously. *Don't stall or block the gui thread!*

Also, binding to `contentHeight` hasn't work as expected for me in many of the cases. What has proven to work is binding to `contentItem.childrenRect.height`. Also, the root item is completely redundant if it is going to be just an empty item, but even if it will have direct children, you can do that with the list view which is also an `Item`.

If you scale the view to the full height, I'd recommend to use a `Column` with a `Repeater` instead. A simple repeater will take advantage of all the model features and efficiencies too, so no worries there.

Comment: Thanks dtech for your detailed answer!